# Per target include(${QT_USE_FILE})

Tags: qt4, cmake

I have CLI based application to which I have decided to add optional QT4 GUI. My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
...
add_library(applib ...
add_executable(app-cli ...
target_link_libraries(app-cli applib)
if(QT4_FOUND)
  ...
  include(${QT_USE_FILE})
  add_executable(app-qt ...
  target_link_libraries(app-qt ${QT_LIBRARIES} applib)
endif()
```

It works, but I have noticed, that whenever "if(QT4_FOUND)" evaluates as true, it adds "-DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG" to compiler calls for **all** source files, including non qt aware code. While benign I consider it unnecessary. As far as I understand the problem, its include(${QT_USE_FILE}) to blame, which includes /usr/share/cmake/Modules/UseQt4.cmake on my machine, where very first non-comment line is:

```
add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
```

While I want probably something like

```
set_target_properties (app-qt PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "${QT_DEFINITIONS}")
```

Can anything be done about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple one solution is to create target in subdirectory. As result `add_definitions` will be called in subdirectory and will not affect current directory.

If it's not acceptable you can solve it another way. Command `add_definitions` modify directory property. So you can simply remove definitions
from list. Try this example:

```
# setted somewhere
add_definitions(-DMYDEFS) # you don't need this
add_definitions(-DMYBoo)

# get definitions
get_directory_property(new_definitions COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)

# remove unnecessary definitions
list(REMOVE_ITEM new_definitions MYDEFS)

# set new definitions
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "${new_definitions}")
```

Note that if definition has form `MYDEF=SOMEVALUE` this will not work. You need to rewrite `list(REMOVE_ITEM ...)`

**PS** I don't know Qt modules usage aspects, probably there is simplier solution or workaround (:

Answer (score 1):

Use CMake 2.8.11 or later , don't use the USE file (You are right, that is the problem) and do use Qt imported targets, like this:

```
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)

add_executable(app-qt ...)
target_link_libraries(app-qt Qt4::QtGui)
# And Qt4::QtNetwork etc if you need that.
```

That will transitively consume the include directories and compile definitions QtGui says it needs (eg -Iinclude/QtGui and -DQT_GUI_LIB), and it is target-scoped, so no other target will be affected.

Everything I described in this talk are a reality in CMake 2.8.11:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJ0kMsLbk6Q